# import data into Oracle 18xe using IMPDP failed

Tags: oracle, impdp, oracle-xe-18.4

I have created a new oracle DB 18xe on a docker.

I am trying to import a dump file using the following command

```
impdp **/**@xepdb1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=file.dmp 
remap_schema='source:dest' logfile=imp.log  CONTENT=DATA_ONLY
```

I am getting the following error

```
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Dec 9 05:39:42 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

ORA-39002: invalid operation
```

I could not figure out why I am getting this error, I tried to import one table only, used the following command

```
impdp **/**@xepdb1 directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=file.dmp 
remap_schema='source:dest' logfile=imp.log  CONTENT=DATA_ONLY  tables=table1
```

I got the following error

```
Import: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Thu Dec 9 05:39:42 2021
Version 18.4.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Connected to: Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production

ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-39166: Object dest.table1 was not found or could not be exported or imported.
```

Appreciate your assistance people.

Comment: Have you considered that the destination table might not be identical in structure to the source table?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `remap_schema` doesn't / shouldn't have single quotes.

```
No : remap_schema='source:dest'

Yes: remap_schema=source:dest
```

See [REMAP_SCHEMA](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-619809A6-1966-42D6-9ACC-A3E0ADC36523) in documentation.

Comment: I removed the single quote, same behavior

Comment: The 2nd import's error says that "object dest.table1 was not found". You were importing DATA_ONLY. Try to first create the table, and then import DATA_ONLY (or - obviously - remove that parameter altogether).

Comment: The table is already created, and without the table clause I get this invalid operation

Comment: Is that the whole error stack? Or are there any other messages? If so, could you post *everything* Oracle says. Not as a comment - edit the original question you posted.

Comment: this is the error I am getting, I am not able to make show more errors, do you know other ways?

Comment: If there's nothing on the screen, does log file contain any additional info?